# Масштаб при поиске по своим объектам полигонам

Tags: yandex-maps-api, search, zoom

На сайте организован поиск по своим объектам (полигоны в geojson) по примеру из песочницы https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search.
По клику на выбранный при поиске полигон устанавливается метка в заранее указанное место на полигоне. Карта центрируется на метке, однако при этом масштаб автоматически устанавливается самый максимальный. Необходимо чтобы метка центрировалась с указанным масштабом или с расчитанным масштабом, позволяющим отобразить весь полигон.
Пробовал отключить центрацию методом "noCentering:true" (хотя по факту она нужна), но при этом выдается ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')".

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальны пример кода, на котором можно воспроизвести описанную ситуацию. А центрировать вам, вероятно лучше было бы задавая bounds карты по границам же полигона, а не угадывать случайный масштаб.

Comment: Вопрос решен при помощи следующего кода:
 mySearchControl.events.add('resultshow', function (event) {
      map.setZoom(14, {duration: 200});
 });